# Errors in PHP file while running a cron job

Tags: php, cron

I am trying to run a php file via cron every 4 days.
It tries to make backups of the files and database.

```
#!/usr/bin/php -q
<?php
if($filecount<=4)
{
$host = "internal-db.host.gridserver.com"; //host name
$username = "user"; //username
$password = "Password"; // your password
$dbname = "Dataabse"; // database name

$dir = "/backup-all";
if(!(file_exists($dir))) {

}

$zip = new ZipArchive();
//backup_tables($host, $username, $password, $dbname);


/* backup the db OR just a table */
function backup_tables1($host,$user,$pass,$name,$tables = '*')
{
$con = mysql_connect($host,$user,$pass);
mysql_select_db($name,$con);

//get all of the tables
if($tables == '*')
{
$tables = array();
$result = mysql_query('SHOW TABLES');
while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result))
{
$tables[] = $row[0];
}
}
else
{
$tables = is_array($tables) ? $tables : explode(',',$tables);
}
$return = "";

//cycle through
foreach($tables as $table)
{
$result = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM '.$table);
$num_fields = mysql_num_fields($result);
$return.= 'DROP TABLE '.$table.';';
$row2 = mysql_fetch_row(mysql_query('SHOW CREATE TABLE '.$table));
$return.= "nn".$row2[1].";nn";

while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result))
{
$return.= 'INSERT INTO '.$table.' VALUES(';
for($j=0; $j<$num_fields; $j++)
{
$row[$j] = addslashes($row[$j]);
$row[$j] = preg_replace("#n#","n",$row[$j]);
if (isset($row[$j])) { $return.= '"'.$row[$j].'"' ; } else { $return.= '""'; }
if ($j<($num_fields-1)) { $return.= ','; }
}
$return.= ");n";
}
$return.="nnn";
}

//save file
$handle = fopen('db-backup-'.time().'-'.(md5(implode(',',$tables))).'.sql','w+');
fwrite($handle,$return);
fclose($handle);
}



if (glob("*.sql") != false)
{
$filecount = count(glob("*.sql"));
$arr_file = glob("*.sql");

for($j=0;$j<$filecount;$j++)
{
$res = $zip->open($arr_file[$j].".zip", ZipArchive::CREATE);
if ($res === TRUE)
{
$zip->addFile($arr_file[$j]);
$zip->close();
unlink($arr_file[$j]);
}
}
}



//get the current folder name-start
$path = dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
$position = strrpos($path,'/') + 1;
$folder_name = substr($path,$position);
//get the current folder name-end



$zipname = date('Y/m/d');
$str = "figata-".$zipname.".zip";
$str = str_replace("/", "-", $str);


// open archive
if ($zip->open($str, ZIPARCHIVE::CREATE) !== TRUE) {
die ("Could not open archive");
}
// initialize an iterator
// pass it the directory to be processed
$iterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator("/home/161441/users/.home/domains/growing-your-business.org/html/"));
// iterate over the directory
// add each file found to the archive

foreach ($iterator as $key=>$value) {
if( strstr(realpath($key), "figata") == FALSE) {
$zip->addFile(realpath($key), $key) or die ("ERROR: Could not add file: $key");
}

}
// close and save archive
$zip->close();


if(glob("*.sql.zip") != false) {
$filecount = count(glob("*.sql.zip"));
$arr_file = glob("*.sql.zip");

for($j=0;$j<$filecount;$j++)
{
unlink($arr_file[$j]);
}
}


//get the array of zip files
if(glob("*.zip") != false) {
$arr_zip = glob("*.zip");
}

//copy the backup zip file to site-backup-figata folder
foreach ($arr_zip as $key => $value) {   // **Line 142**
if (strstr($value, "figata")) {
$delete_zip[] = $value;
copy("$value", "$dir/$value");
}
}


for ($i=0; $i < count($delete_zip); $i++) {
unlink($delete_zip[$i]);
}

$dir ="home/domains/growing-your-business.org/backup-growing/";//dir absolute path
$interval = strtotime('-96 hours');//files older than 24hours

foreach (glob($dir."*.zip") as $file) // **Line 157**
    //delete if older
    if (filemtime($file) <= $interval ) unlink($file);

echo '<script>alert("Archive created successfully.")</script>';
}
else
{
    echo '<script>alert("Archive Not created successfully.")</script>';
}
?>
```

When it runs via http, the function works properly. But when it runs via Cron, I get the following errors:

```
    Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /nfs/c05/h05/mnt/161441/domains/growing-your-business.org/html/backup-growing.php on line 142

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /nfs/c05/h05/mnt/161441/domains/growing-your-business.org/html/backup-growing.php on line 157
<script>alert("Archive created successfully.")</script>
```

Can anyone please help me on this???

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: can you highlight which lines are 142 and 157

Comment: Can you please try and indent the code?. I find it very hard to read it...

Comment: at first site it looks like a problem with paths. As the CLI runs from another 'working directory' then the webserver. You should run the script from the CLI manually and put some debugging statements on the proper places, eg. `print_r($iterator);`.

Comment: Further to @giorgio's observation, `$dir ="home/domains/` should be `$dir ="/home/domains/` the absolute path must start with a `/` otherwise the path is appended to current location

Comment: the `glob` may return `false`

Comment: @DannyHearnah I have highlighted the code for Line nos 142 and 157. I am Using the absolute path now and will update the results here in few minutes.

Comment: @DannyHearnah   the results are same. I have absolute paths this time.

Answer (score 0):

**For line 142**

you either check that `$arr_zip` isset first, or define it..

```
$arr_zip = array( ); //create an empty array

//get the array of zip files
if(glob("*.zip") != false) {
    $arr_zip = glob("*.zip");
}

//copy the backup zip file to site-backup-figata folder
foreach ($arr_zip as $key => $value) {   // **Line 142**
    if (strstr($value, "figata")) {
        $delete_zip[] = $value;
        copy("$value", "$dir/$value");
    }
}
```

or

```
if( isset( $arr_zip ) )
{
    foreach ($arr_zip as $key => $value) {   // **Line 142**
        if (strstr($value, "figata")) {
            $delete_zip[] = $value;
            copy("$value", "$dir/$value");
        }
    }
}
```

I would prefer defining it rather than checking it isset.

**For Line 157**

Pretty much replicate how you do line 142:

```
$files = array( );

if( glob($dir."*.zip") != false ) {
    $files = glob($dir."*.zip");
}
foreach ($files as $file) // **Line 157**
```